# What do the args and kwargs do in pandas.DataFrame.clip?

Tags: python, pandas

I've been working on the documentation for `pandas.DataFrame.clip`.  I need to document what the `*args` and `**kwargs` do for that function.

[Here](https://github.com/Dpananos/pandas/blob/docstring_clip/pandas/core/generic.py#L5599) is a link to the branch I am working on.  The  `*args` and `**kwargs` are passed to a function called `validate_clip_with_axis`.  [Here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/compat/numpy/function.py#L137) is the code for that function.

I'm not really sure what `validate_clip_with_axis` is doing or how the `*args` and `**kwargs` play a role in `pandas.DataFrame.clip`.  In particular, I'm not even sure what sorts of argument I can include in `*args` and `**kwargs`.

What does `validate_clip_with_axis` do?  How does it relate to `pandas.DataFrame.clip`?  Could someone provide me with an example?

Comment: Why are you taking it upon yourself to write that documentation? It seems like this should be done by someone intimately familiar with the function, ideally the person or people who have written or made changes to that function. A random answer on StackOverflow is probably not a good enough source to cover all the details and caveats.

Comment: I am no expert with pandas internals, but you should know that pandas functions are capable of being called through numpy. So, if you call `np.clip(df)`, it internally calls `pd.DataFrame.clip` with the very same arguments. `np.clip` accepts certain parameters, these are accepted as-is by `pd.DataFrame.clip` thanks to `args` and `kwargs` but what is done with them, I don't know.

Comment: @AlexHall It was part of the sprint today, and a good way to learn about contributing to OSS.

Comment: Note also that [pandas 0.17 documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.clip.html) does not include these parameters. Provided functionality is unchanged, it is worth investigating what triggered their introduction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They seem to be used for compatibility with numpy libraries [1] in this file [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/fb556ed64cd0e905e31fe39723a8a4bca9cb112d/pandas/compat/numpy/function.py#L137).

In the original file, args, kwargs are being passed into [nv.validate_clip_with_axis](https://github.com/Dpananos/pandas/blob/7c14e4f14aff216be558bf5d4d2d00b4838c2360/pandas/core/generic.py#L5604). Note that `nv` is imported [here](https://github.com/Dpananos/pandas/blob/7c14e4f14aff216be558bf5d4d2d00b4838c2360/pandas/core/generic.py#L51).

Since these are only used internally, and, as jpp pointed out, not even exposed in the [Pandas docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.clip.html), you probably don't need to worry about documenting them.

[1] https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/fb556ed64cd0e905e31fe39723a8a4bca9cb112d/pandas/compat/numpy/function.py#L1-L19